# Recover files deleted with rsync -avz --delete

Tags: linux, rsync, ubuntu-11.10, ext4

Is it possible to recover files deleted with rsync -avz --delete?
If it is, what are some suggested tools to do so?

Comment: Yes, restore from backup... This depends on your OS, filesystem, and possibly other details. This type of question isn't really on-topic on Stack Overflow. (Please _search_ on Super User. You'll find a lot of resources already there.)

Comment: Sadly it was the backup files that were deleted. How can I move my question to Super User? I couldn't find a question on Super User describing this same situation (rsync --delete). I'm not sure if the manner in which files were deleted matters in this case, so I'm hesitant to try some ext4 file recovery tools.

Comment: `rsync` isn't relevant. You need data recovery tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to get extundelete to work, so I ended up using photorec + find/grep in order to recover my important files.

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate?

Comment: What else do you want to know?

Comment: @Skim Did using photorec + find/grep recover deleted files or did it just find copies of the files that existed elsewhere?

Comment: photorec recovered deleted files.
find/grep were needed since photorec chooses arbitrary names for the recovered files.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you ran rsync on some unix system.
If you don't have a backup of your file system, 
then its a long tedious process recovering deleted files from unix file system.
High level steps :

1. find partition where your file resided
2. create image of entire partition `% dd if=/partition of=partition.img ..`
   (this assumes you have enough space to store this somewhere locally in a different partition, or you can copy it over to different system `% dd if=/partition | ssh otherhost "dd of=partition.img"`)
3. open the img file in hex edit
   (this assumes you know the contents of the files that you've lost and can identify them when you see the content.)
4. note the byte offset and length of your file
5. use `grep -b` to extract the contents of your missing file.

enjoy!

Comment: Do you have any experience with some ext4 recovery tools such as testdisk or extundelete? Just wondering if one tool is more popular/successful.

Comment: Taking a snapshot is really important and should be the first step. Possibly compress if it doesn't fit otherwise and see if you can mount it from within the compression.